# Do Editorial Articles get indexed in SCOPUS and WOS?

Tags: publications, journals, elsevier, scopus

I am editing a couple of special issues for two reputed journals that are indexed in SCOPUS, SCI, and WOS. Currently, I am writing the editorial articles for both of these special issues. Since these types of editorials do not go through the peer review process, the decision to include them in the publications maybe made by the Editor-in-Chief. Therefore, I am curious whether these publications will be indexed in the SCOPUS and WOS databases.

Comment: You could easily just find a previous article of this type and look in the databases to find the answer yourself

Comment: You should ask the people who sell you the data in SCOPUS, SCI, and WOS what their datasets include!